# Почему Reader.Read() начинает чтение не с первой строки данного столбца? Класс Oledb.Или может он ее перескакивает?

Tags: c#, winforms, oledb

Проблема в том что я вызываю Reader.read() при открытии формы .И  reader возвращает не первую строку ,а вторую строку столбца . Как мне возвратить именно первую? А если убрать Read.Read() он мне ничего не возвратит,потому что ничего я не прочитал.Тем кто откликнется буду рад ,искал в интернете ,на подобную проблему не натолкнулся.

```
private void Form5_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        Connection.Open();

        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("SELECT *FROM [Тесты] WHERE [Название предмета] = @NamePred AND [Название теста] = @NameTest", Connection);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("NamePred", pred);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("NameTest", test);
     
        OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();


        
        string[] arrayOtvet = new string[7];
        const int n = 6;
        int[] perm = Enumerable.Range(0, n).ToArray();
        
        
        

            Random r = new Random();
            for (int i = n - 1; i >= 1; i--)
            {
                int j = r.Next(i + 1);

                int temp = perm[j];
                perm[j] = perm[i];
                perm[i] = temp;
            }
            reader.Read();
            label1.Text = reader[2].ToString();
            arrayOtvet[5] = reader[3].ToString();
            arrayOtvet[4] = reader[4].ToString();
            arrayOtvet[3] = reader[5].ToString();
            arrayOtvet[2] = reader[6].ToString();
            arrayOtvet[1] = reader[7].ToString();
            arrayOtvet[0] = reader[8].ToString();
        



        radioButton1.Text = arrayOtvet[perm[0]];
        radioButton2.Text = arrayOtvet[perm[1]];
        radioButton3.Text = arrayOtvet[perm[2]];
        radioButton4.Text = arrayOtvet[perm[3]];
        radioButton5.Text = arrayOtvet[perm[4]];
        radioButton6.Text = arrayOtvet[perm[5]];

        if (radioButton1.Text != "")
        {
            radioButton1.Visible = true;
        
        }
        if (radioButton2.Text != "")
        {
            radioButton2.Visible = true;

        }
        if (radioButton3.Text != "")
        {
            radioButton3.Visible = true;

        }

        if (radioButton4.Text != "")
        {
            radioButton4.Visible = true;

        }

        if (radioButton5.Text != "")
        {
            radioButton5.Visible = true;

        }

        if (radioButton6.Text != "")
        {
            radioButton6.Visible = true;

        }
        
        Connection.Close();

    }
```

Я прикрепил изображение с таблицей к которой я обращаюсь ,возвращает мне значения 2-ой строки ,а необходимо первую.
[image]

Comment: Смотрели ли вы все записи до конца? Вообще-то

Comment: Можно поподробней?

Comment: В таблице базы данных нет такого понятия как "первая" или "вторая" строка. Вы **обязаны** указать способ сортировки.

Comment: Не понимаю что за способ сортировки ,можно подробнее?